# Different ip's for different locations with one domain

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I saw many big websites have different servers in different countries. But how can they set different servers for different locations? I know there is dns load balancing, but as far as I know it only supports round-robin.

e.g. Domain is example.com

```
User from USA: Get server in USA
User from Germany: Get server in France
User from China: Get server in China
```

Comment: Another option is anycast. Same address, different localized servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many DNS providers that provide Geo-based name resolution. Use one of those, or preferably just serve your contents from a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

AWS [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) DNS system is one provider that does this. Use the [geolocation routing policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html). The cost is minimal. AWS can of course host virtual servers in any of their many data centers for you as well, and has dozens of other services you can use.

There will be many other DNS providers that provide geolocation DNS services, but I don't know any offhand.